# How do I change the setPosition of a layer mid animation

Tags: objective-c, position, core-animation

I am currently animating an objects `position` to move across the x-axis in intervals of 50. However, I want to be able to stop the object and change its animation during certain circumstances, such as the user laying an object in front of it.

I have to use `[self.layer setPosition:newPosition]` or the object will bounce back to its original position after animation completes. If the object is dropped to stop it, the object bounces to the `setPosition` point before committing the new animation. How do I make it stop and stay where it is AND perform a new animation?

Answer (score 1):

You are using implicit layer animation to animate the positions of your layers. To cancel an animation before it is complete, you would use:

```
[self.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

This would have the side effect of jumping your layer to the final animation position. If you want the layer to stop where it is, then you need to get the current `presentationLayer` position.

```
CGPoint currentAnimationPosition = self.presentationLayer.position;
self.layer.position = currentAnimationPosition;
[self.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

To perform a new animation, you can simply set a new position on the layer as you were doing before.